# C# how to create a log file from multiple textboxes?

Tags: c#

Initially the idea was to create a simple empty file containing only the date it was created.
But now I need to create a log file with the contents of 2 different textBoxes (textBoxName and textBoxPhone).
Below is the code I have so far, only to create an empty log file with the date/time stamp in its filename:

```
string myFileName = String.Format ("(0). (1)", DateTime. Now. ToString("yyyy Mddhhnnss"), "log");
string myFullPath = Path.Combine("D: \\", myFileName);
using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText (myFullPath))
{
sw.WriteLine(sw);
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Consider creating a simple class that has two string properties, `Name` and `Phone`. When you want to write this to disk, create an instance of the class, initialize those two properties from your text boxes and then _serialize_ that instance to JSON (using either the Newtonsoft or System.Text.Json serializers). Then write the JSON to disk. That way, you can read it back in and _deserialize_ the JSON back to a class instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi please take a close look at the adjustments I made.

```
string myFileName = String.Format("{0}.{1}", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss"), "log");
string myFullPath = Path.Combine(@"C:\temp", myFileName);
using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(myFullPath))
{
       string content = String.Format("{0};{1}", textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);
       sw.WriteLine(content);
}
```